# How to scope a variable to a class in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a class using the class foo {} syntax, and want a private variable inside of it. Right now, I have something like this:

```
'use strict';
class foo {
  constructor(x1,y1) {
    var x = x1;
    var y = y1;
  }
  get x() {
    return x;
  }
  get y() {
    return y;
  }
}
```

Whenever I try to access foo.x and foo.y, I get a x is not found error. However, when I tried putting the variable declarations outside of the constructor, it stopped working. I'm also using static methods, so I can't abandon the class syntax without some work. How can I fix this? How can I declare a variable inside of the object, that is global and can't be found outside?

Comment: Have you tried writing `this.x = x1;` instead of var?

Comment: @GabrieleB-David declaring `this.x` would allow access to `x` from outside the class.

Comment: @realseanp you're right. I missed the part where he said "private variable". I guess my elementary school teachers were right all those years ago: read the whole question before answering :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those getters are declared on the prototype, where they cannot access the private (scoped) variables in the constructor. You'll need to use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) for creating instance-specific getters:

```
class Foo {
  constructor(x, y) {
    Object.defineProperties(this, {
      x: {get() { return x; }, configurable: true},
      y: {get() { return y; }, configurable: true}
    });
  }
}
```

This is no different than in ES5. Btw, given you don't assign to the variables, you might as well make them non-writable properties.

Comment: How could I make a variable/property that is only writable inside of the instance?

Comment: @Wyrme `x` and `y` (the parameters) already are exactly such variables

Answer (score 1):

Well people are assuming you want to use getters and setters. If that's not the case, this will suffice:

```js
'use strict';
class foo {
  constructor(x1,y1) {
    this.x = x1;
    this.y = y1;
  }
}

var f = new foo(10, 20);

console.log(f.x)
console.log(f.y)
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gLxnqfrv/

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [es6-features](http://es6-features.org/#GetterSetter) this is the correct syntax for a class and it's getters and setters.

> ```
> class Rectangle {
>     constructor (width, height) {
>         this._width  = width
>         this._height = height
>     }
>     set width  (width)  { this._width = width               }
>     get width  ()       { return this._width                }
>     set height (height) { this._height = height             }
>     get height ()       { return this._height               }
>     get area   ()       { return this._width * this._height }
> }
> var r = new Rectangle(50, 20)
> r.area === 1000
> ```

Important to note that there is no requirement to damage the prototype in ES6.